# JWrapper windows shortcuts broken

Tags: jwrapper

JWrapper support now redirects to StackOverflow, so I'm posting here.

The Windows shortcuts created by JWrapper don't work; they point to a location which doesn't exist; I can verify this by navigating to the directory pointed to in the properties of the shortcut:

```
C:\Users\jchrist\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-SampleApp
```

and seeing that the expected `SampleAppWinLauncher.exe` isn't there.

I can reproduce this simply with a slight modification of the SampleApp.  Open the jwrapper-sampleapp.xml file and copy main virtual app, but give it a different name:

```
    <App>
      <Name>SampleApp2</Name>
      <LogoPNG>sampleapp/logo.png</LogoPNG>
      <MainClass>jwrapper.SampleApp</MainClass>
      <Param>one</Param>
      <Param>two</Param>
    </App>
```

If you do this, and then run the 32-bit offline installer, you'll get a dialog which allows you to select which of the two virtual apps you want to launch.

After selecting one of the (identical) virtual apps and quiting it, the shortcuts provided in the start menu in the SampleApp folder do not work.  If you dig into the properties of the shortcuts, you can see they point to an executable which doesn't exist.  (It did exist, but it deletes itself after the first run).

I'm using the latest JWrapper (jwrapper-00036138363.jar, although this problem existed with jwrapper-00035090611.jar) as well.

Comment: If I do this on Win7 or XP with the latest JWrapper jar, things work as expected.   The problem described here does exist on Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this on Windows 7 today and it works OK.  I haven't tested this on server 2008 but Windows 7 is treated basically the same as Server 2008 by JWrapper.  Also the executable disappearing after the first run is not normal behaviour.

My guess would be that this is antivirus software that is detecting the run as a false positive and deleting the executable.  Do you have any AV software installed? can you turn it off to test?

Unfortunately some AV software will delete files etc without any warning.