# latest JWrapper (00036138363) fails to produce launchable programs on windows

Tags: jwrapper

If you build SampleApp with the latest (i.e. May 25th's) JWrapper, it won't start on windows.  According to SampleApp-SampleApp..log, it appears to be trying to load a MacOSX class (JWOSXEventListener) at runtime:

```
87342876 (+    0) STDOUT test
87342876 (+    0) STDERR test
87342876 (+    0) [LogFolderCleaner] Keeping Wrapper-2015-05-26-17-42-08-852.log
87342876 (+    0) [LogFolderCleaner] Keeping SampleApp-SampleApp-2015-05-26-17-42-22-876.log
87342876 (+    0) [LogFolderCleaner] Keeping GenericUpdater-2015-05-26-17-42-18-945.log
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] App Bundle Name:    SampleApp
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] App Bundle Version: 00036171806
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] Virtual App:        SampleApp
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] Update URL:         http://0.0.254.254/
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] App Folder:         C:\Users\christop\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-SampleApp\JWrapper-SampleApp-00036171806-complete
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] JRE:                C:\Users\christop\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-SampleApp\JWrapper-Windows32JRE-00036170991-complete
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] JRE Version:        1.7.0_05
87342876 (+    0) [JWrapper] Proxy:              null
87342876 (+    0) [EDT Exception Printer] Catching all EDT and uncaught exceptions and printing
87342892 (+   16) [JWrapperNative] Detected 32-bit architecture
87342892 (+    0) [JWrapperNative] Detected Windows OS
87342892 (+    0) [JWrapper] Is Process DPI Aware: true
87342892 (+    0) [JWrapper] sun.java2d.dpiaware: null
87342892 (+    0) [JWDetectedProxy] No proxy configuration found to load.
87342892 (+    0) JVM Option: -Xmx256m
87342892 (+    0) [JWrapper] JVM Home: C:\Users\christop\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-SampleApp\JWrapper-Windows32JRE-00036170991-complete
87342908 (+   16) [PermissionsUtil] Setting permissions for C:\Users\christop\AppData\Roaming\JWrapper-SampleApp\JWApps\JRE-LastSuccessfulOptions-JWrapper-Windows32JRE-00036170991-complete to F
87342908 (+    0) [PermissionsUtil] Finished setting permissions.
87342908 (+    0) [JWrapper] Wrote JVM Options OK
87342908 (+    0) [AWT/Swing Exception] (STDERR) Exception on thread main (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jwrapper/hidden/events/JWOSXEventListener)
87342923 (+   15) java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jwrapper/hidden/events/JWOSXEventListener
87342923 (+    0)   at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at jwrapper.JWrapper.main(JWrapper.java:290)
87342923 (+    0) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jwrapper.hidden.events.JWOSXEventListener
87342923 (+    0)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
87342923 (+    0)   ... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where JWrapper loads the app class, the exception is due to the class failing to load, this is due to a bug in the sample app code which references a class which has been moved in the latest JW build.

Comment: Ok, I can verify after rebuilding SampleApp from source with the latest jars from jwrapperlib that the application does launch.  The problem detailed at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30471288/jwrapper-windows-shortcuts-broken) still exists, even with the latest JWrapper jar.